# value in database 'members' shows a link when user is an admin

Tags: php, database, mysqli, admin

I hope my question is not hard to answer, i tried to check this here but i couldn't find the answer i seek. Even tried Google but he didn't understand the question ;).

**So here is my question:**

I have a database called members and there is a row that is called admin. I have 2 values in there: YES and NO (might change that to 0 or 1).

YES = You are an admin

NO = You are not an admin

Now i wonder how to get a link appear when someone is an admin in html/php when users have YES (or 1) as value in the row admin in the database and when there is NO (or 0) then he shows nothing.

How do i do that?

Comment: simple if statement. If you are writting a class to encapsulate  your user logic, something like:`if($user->isAdmin()){//show link}`

Comment: If you question is about how to query the database to get the value, you should say so

Comment: Use a [`WHERE`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-where/) clause. There's also `while($row...` then `if($row['col'] == "admin"){ echo "Admin"; }else{ echo "NOT admin.";}`

Comment: Oops.  `if($row['col'] == "YES"){ echo "Admin"; }else{ echo "NOT admin.";}` - am sure you get the drift though ;)

Comment: `SELECT * FROM mytable` while on your result `if($row['admin']=="1")echo 'i m admin !';` or `if($row['admin'])echo 'i m admin !';` may work too

Comment: `$row['col']` -> that's wrong, i think he was mistaken word

Comment: @BenjaminPoignant It's an example. You're welcome to put in an answer ;)

Comment: Okay guys, i made a mistake and i dropped on what i did with your answers above in my original post.. I just do not see it what i doing wrong there...