# When value is met in database from logging in then show a link when he/she is admin

Tags: php, database, session, mysqli, admin

### Explaining the problem

My original post is this: [value in database 'members' shows a link when user is an admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27066219/value-in-database-members-shows-a-link-when-user-is-an-admin)
BUT i have a feeling that i do it totally wrong here with connecting to the result i try to achieve.

### The code that goes into the page where it need to show

```
1 <?php 
2 include 'db_connect.php';
3
4 $results = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM member");
5 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
5 if($row['admin'] == "YES"){ echo "Admin"; }else{ echo "NOT admin.";}
7 ?>
```

The thing is, i logged in with someone that does not has the powers of admin, sees ADMIN on the page. I might made a wrong code here and i try to understand what i do wrong but i just do not see it...

Now i realize also that i have a session running in the background to see who that is and i display that user also on the screen like: Welcome *NameUser*

### The code for starting the session when you log in

```
1 ob_start();
2 session_start();
3
4 $username = $_POST['username'];
5 $password = $_POST['password'];
6 
7 $conn = mysqli_connect('****', '****', '****', '****');
8 
9 $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $username);
10 $query = "SELECT id, admin, username, password, salt
11           FROM member
12           WHERE username = '$username';";
13 
14 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
15 
16 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) // User not found. So, redirect to login_form again.
17 {
18    header('Location: login.php');
19 }
20 
21 $userData = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
22 $hash = hash('sha256', $userData['salt'] . hash('sha256', $password) );
23  
24 if($hash != $userData['password']) 
25 {
26    header('Location: login.php');
27 }else {
28  session_regenerate_id();
29  $_SESSION['sess_user_id'] = $userData['id'];
30  $_SESSION['sess_username'] = $userData['username'];
31  $_SESSION['sess_admin'] = $userData['admin'];
32  session_write_close();
33  header('Location: home.php');
34 }
35 }
```

---

### Question

Do i also need to change the $sessions to let my code work and how do i do that or does then a whole new approach when there is an session running in the background to get that link showed when he/she is an admin?

Comment: You do not have any WHERE clause in the statement `$results = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM member");` so it's just going to pull all results from the db - presumably the first row it's selecting is an admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stored admin in a session use :

```
if ($_SESSION['sess_admin']=="YES"){ echo "Admin"; }else{ echo "NOT admin.";}
```

Comment: Thx, this was actually what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment, there's no WHERE clause in the first code block. So you have verified the user exists and password is valid, then redirect them 'home' but then you do not select the specific user when displaying the page. Something like the below should work -

```
<?php 
include 'db_connect.php';
$results = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM member WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['sess_user_id']."'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
if($row['admin'] == "YES"){ echo "Admin"; }else{ echo "NOT admin.";}
?>
```

Or as mentioned by Alex - you have already selected the users admin status and stored it in a session - so if that's all you need to check then there's no need to hit the database again.